# How to always fetch CSS and not use cached copy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

using HTML5+CSS3+jQuery.

Since I am changing my CSS file frequently, I would like to force users' browsers always to fetch the CSS file and never use the cached version.

I found that I should write something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css?t=[...some unique id...]"/>
```

How can I automatically generate such unique Id? ( maybe current time?)

Thanks

Comment: Why is your CSS changing so frequently? Users are going to pay a heavy price for this, you should make sure it's really the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks@Godwin.. Actually, this CSS is ultra-light. But I do want it to be downloaded always. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS is small and dynamic, your best solution would be to inject it inline in the `<head>` using `<style>` tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

This way your styles will be updated on every page refresh and you will not need to wait for an additional http request.

For example, if your stylesheet looks like this:

```
/* This stuff hardly ever changes */
html {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* This stuff changes all the time */
body {
    background-image: url('todays-image.png');
}
```

And your html looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Change the css to look like this:

```
/* This stuff hardly ever changes */
html {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

And the html to look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
        <style>
            /* This stuff changes all the time */
            body {
                background-image: url('todays-image.png');
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

If all of the contents of `index.css` change frequently, you can remove the file entirely and remove the `link` tag.

Comment: Thanks. And is it possible to generate somehow a unique ID tha I will use as a querystring parameter?

Comment: You won't need to use it for this solution, don't link to the actual stylesheet but instead dump its contents within a style tag. See @Boltz answer if you really need to do it that way.

Comment: @Greg, I edited the answer to give you an example of what I mean.

Comment: Thank you Godwin (+1), but my file it pretty long and it would not be nce-coding to put it in the HTML. I am not looking for alternative ways to do it. Rather, just for a way to generate a unique link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a server timestamp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

A better Idea is to use a version of your css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?version=<?php echo $CSS_VERSION; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). Sound like a great idea, but I am not using PHP. Pure HTML+CSS+JS/jquery. Is there any way do it ?

Comment: Do you have a templating engine ?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular issue, you could inject the link via javascript using ticks. In this example the code would insert the css as the last styleset processed. I would recommend doing this on the back-end though.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var sourceName = 'test.css?v=' + ((new Date().getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000); // using ticks
            var linkElement = document.createElement('link');
            linkElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
            linkElement.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
            linkElement.setAttribute('href', sourceName);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(linkElement);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tested it before publishing it and went through various methods. Many did not execute the href change. It only seemed to execute if it was injected into the DOM.